# I am a new female supervisor in a small firm. Two of my male staff are Muslim. What do I need to know?

Tags: professionalism

On the first day when I was being introduced one of the gentlemen ignored/refused to shake my hand and I believe we both felt embarrassed and slightly offended. I have learned that this man is devout. I wish to know what issues might cause concern. I wonder about the fact that there is only one washroom for both men and women. Also, I wonder about my wardrobe choices particularly in the summer months (sandals without nylons) and when we need to go outside to look at a site (sleeveless top). One warm day I took my business jacket off (as did all the men) and was wearing a sleeveless blouse and noted that he did not contribute to the discussion.
He is a star performer and I wish to enable both of us to obtain our best performance and productivity in a comfortable working environment. Any input or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The Israelis have a ton of experience dealing with conservative Jews and Muslims in the workplace. I'd say that if you don't find any satisfactory answers from us, you should haunt their online forums for some kind of answer. I appreciate your good faith effort to accommodate him. Accommodating any conservative's religion is never easy because of the enhanced likelyhood that someone will quote their religion and draw a line in the sand.

Comment: This question should be helpful to you: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15336/what-do-i-have-to-consider-when-working-with-muslim-colleagues.

Comment: @Anthony, I would even say that this is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I think the supervisor/employee relationship changes the power dynamic somewhat.  The other question is about peers.  Answers here may well draw from that question, though.

Comment: How about talking to him about this?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're having to change your wardrobe and wear things that make you less comfortable, you're sacrificing your own performance for his. That's still not optimal, you're just making his problem into your problem.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Actually, the second sentence of that question says "Technically she's my subordinate, so I want to avoid as many pitfalls as possible."

Comment: @DavidK oh, I missed that.  (That said, male supervisor/female subordinate might still be different than the reverse.  That's for the community to decide.)

Comment: I would say accommodate his beliefs as much as possible within reason. Anything beyond that - and it's a line YOU have to draw - just means he can either suck it up or work elsewhere.

Comment: How interesting.  Good luck!  He won't shake your hand. Women are usually not in power over men in this reglious ideology.  So you may find this awkward.

He will probably not eat lunch with you at the same table and he may bring his own utensils to work.  He will even try to escape on Friday at lunchtime to go off for prayers.  Presumably that was allowed in his contract.

Answer (score 20):

There are so many different believes and sects within those that you will not come to any results on your own.

You will need to ask them.

Schedule a meting with them, tell them in advance what you told us, so they can prepare and listen to what they have to say. As they may not follow the same religious guidelines, you should schedule a single meeting with each. It goes without saying that for this meetings, you should err on the side of caution and dress very conservative.

Make sure you tell them that you will *try* to make it work. In the end, you will need to decide what exactly is worth it to accomodate them and what is not.  You are running a business (or have been employed to do so). If religion gets in the way of said business, you will have to make some tough decisions.

Comment: I would talk to HR first and see if they want to attend the meeting.  One washroom is an HR thing.  It is great OP is trying to accommodate.  I don't like the term "try to make it work" as that implies something is not working.  "Are there religious beliefs or practices that effect the work place I should be aware of".  You don't have to commit to address all of even some.  Just asking the question is the correct message.  If they come out thinking you are going to all and only address 70% they may think they were shorted 30%.

Comment: I would also suggest you talk to the person who hired you - what was their train of thought for putting you in that position.

Comment: +1 for "ask them". Whether you're dealing with someone from a different culture, different religion, or some sort of disability, the best thing is to ask them what sort of accommodation would help.

Comment: @AleAssis Perhaps she just happened to be the best candidate..? Her gender should not have come into it if she was otherwise capable of doing the job.

Comment: @JaneS, actually her gender should matter, unless you are saying that their religion doesn't matter and they should go against their religious beliefs.  While we need to learn to work with those around us, IMHO, management should have known better than to create a situation of such conflict, unless of course they have a larger plan, in which case AleAssis is correct to say OP should talk to the decision makers.

Comment: Excuse me, but management should hire the best person for the job, regardless of gender. If there is an employee that has a problem with that, for example for religious reasons, that's that employee's problem. On the other hand, we have no indication that there is actually a problem. "I can't shake hands with a woman that I'm not married to for religious reason" is not a problem.

Comment: If a company has an anti-black racist employee who works absolutely fine because all the other employees are white by coincidence, should that company avoid hiring black people? I don't think they should, and I don't think they would be allowed to.

Comment: @gnasher729 pretty much exactly covered my points :)

Comment: Also, consider the alternate case.  If there was a female staff member, would you not hire a Muslim employee even if they were ten steps ahead of any other candidate?  No, of course not, it's discrimination.

Comment: @JaneS If you have the belief that a characteristic of an individual *should* not matter, and then blindly *assume* that it actually does not matter, you probably should not be handling personnel decisions.  "Best candidate" is a holistic thing, not "if I just cut this part out of a person, the remainder is perfect."  The extreme case gnasher729 listed of not hiring black people is a straw man due to the legal concerns of racism. If you have someone who has distasteful beliefs, you don't have to put them in positions of power. Find ways to place them such that their beliefs are not a problem..

Comment: .. which are potentially 'below their station' because their beliefs do not fit with the company values, and those beliefs are affecting the company's ability to do its job.  If there is no where to put them, encourage them to find other employement.  However, giving a sexist pig an entire staff of nothing except well endowed women with a predilection towards dressing provocatively will not solve the problem that you have a sexist pig in a position where you should not have a sexist pig. Now if this sexist pig is a Turing or an Einstein or a Jobs or a Feneyman in your workplace, this may be...

Comment: ... a problem.  If it is, then the situation is unique enough that we don't have to fall back on universal objective statements about all people.  We can solve the problem regarding a single individual.  That change in approach can unshackle your hands quite quickly.  For instance, maybe its worth raising your unit price *just* to maintain an inefficient staffing structure which isolates the undesirable traits of someone deemed essential to the company's bottom line.

Answer (score 11):

If you are not a Muslim, then you don't need to live under Islamic rules regarding clothing, or anything else. The workplace is not for religion any more than it is appropriate for politics or other irrelevant personal things. For example if you had an employee who was anti-semitic, would it be your responsibility to make sure they never had to work with any Jews? Of course not, it's the employees responsibility to act professionally and leave their ideological issues at home.

You already know how to handle this situation. If they were homophobes, racists, or misogynists I doubt you would be asking this question, because it's a no-brainer. Treat everyone equally, and handle unprofessional behavior stemming from religious ideology the same way you would handle it coming from anywhere else.

Comment: While your opinion may be an ideal scenario for you, the reality is that religion and ideology do come into the workplace, so this doesn't really help the OP, who needs a practical solution in order to ensure the team works well together.

Comment: Why the minuses? This sounds perfectly reasonable to me. It's their attitude that caused the problem, not her. 
We allow women wear sleeveless blouses in our culture. Why would she be the one to  adapt?

Comment: @Luntri As Rory states, the downvotes are presumably because this doesn't answer the question. It may be true that the OP doesn't *need* to *do* anything, but that's not even what she's asking: she just wants to be prepared for certain issues that *could* come up.  Basically, user11177 is just championing the idea that religion doesn't belong in the workplace which is neither realistic nor useful to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite likely that the two gentlemen in question have more experience in contact with members of a different religion than you have, and quite possible that they take their religion more serious than you do.

We assume that you have no intentions to hurt anyone's feeling, but on the other hand it will happen due to lack of knowledge. I think you should make it clear to both that if you do anything that conflicts with their religion, they must not suffer silently or get annoyed with you, but MUST tell you what the problem is so that it can be fixed.

Comment: So as this person's supervisor, would you put ketchup on a hotdog in front of that person? I would call any supervisor doing that grossly incompetent. I find your "minor concession" very strange. "Allowing them to explain" is a concession? Open communication is absolutely essential about everywhere. It's not a "minor concession".

Comment: Somehow I think I would be very careful hiring you.